# How to find City name from String which came from Google Maps API

Tags: java, string, substring

I am having 2 Textbox in my application. 1 for Source address and another for Destination Address. Both are AutoComplete textbox and I am getting Data from Google Maps API.

**Source Address** == SHAHIBAUGUNDERBRIDGE,Shahibagh,**Ahmedabad**,Gujarat

**Destination Address** == CGRoad,ShreyasColony,Navrangpura,**Ahmedabad**,Gujarat

Now what i want is to find the City Name which user has enter from the string. I tried different ways but as we can see that format of Address String is not fixed I am not able to get the City Name. I figure out one thing which is common to get city name is that it will always before the last ",". As you can see that City name -> Ahmedabad in both the String is before the last (COMMA)",". But still I am struggling to get the City Name. If any one has any idea please kindly help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it always the second to last then try

```
String [] vals = source_address.split(",");
String city = vals[vals.length - 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like google is saving the address as:

[roads], [name of location], [city], [state].

Assuming you are correct then that the city is always before the last "," then you could use the split() method on the string.

split takes in a regex (as a string) to use to split up the string in question. However it seems you just want to split on ","

So if you called:

```
String [] data = myAddress.split(","); // assuming "myAddress" has the Google data
```

Then you now have in data an array of strings. one element for each section between a ",".

If you wanted to access the next-to-last element of that array it would simply be:

```
String cityName = data[data.length-2]; // get the 2ed to last element
```

Now remember, "split()" takes a regex, so be aware of the string you pass it.